# Use anchor from the next upper object

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints, anchor

At the moment I am coding an Event-`UIViewController` which has three `UITableViews` displaying the participants, the intresteds and the people who can't come. Each one of them is anchored right under a Label.
The hierarchy looks like this:

> `descriptionLabel` | `surePeopleLabel` | `surePeopleTV` | `maybePeopleLabel` | `maybePeopleTV` | `nopePeopleLabel` | `nopePeopleTV`

Now I only want to display the Labels and TableViews which are relevant. For example if there are no interested people, it should not display the associated Elements.

But this leads to a problem: Because the `nopePeopleLabel`'s constraint is set to the *bottomAnchor* of the `maybePeopleTV`which was never added, the program crashes.

Does anyone know a (smooth) approach to set an anchor to the next existing upper object?
I added my code even though It is not necessary..

```swift
if let sureUsers = surePeopleTV.users, !sureUsers.isEmpty {
    scrollView.addSubview(surePeopleLabel)
    scrollView.addSubview(surePeopleTV)
    let sureTVHeight: CGFloat = CGFloat(sureUsers.count) * 60
    surePeopleLabel.anchor(top: descLabel.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 20, paddingLeft: padding, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: padding, width: 0, height: 0)
    surePeopleTV.anchor(top: surePeopleLabel.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 5, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: sureTVHeight)
}

if let maybeUsers = maybePeopleTV.users, !maybeUsers.isEmpty {
    scrollView.addSubview(maybePeopleLabel)
    scrollView.addSubview(maybePeopleTV)
    let maybeTVHeight: CGFloat = CGFloat(maybeUsers.count) * 60
    maybePeopleLabel.anchor(top: surePeopleTV.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 20, paddingLeft: padding, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: padding, width: 0, height: 0)
    maybePeopleTV.anchor(top: maybePeopleLabel.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 5, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: maybeTVHeight)
}

if let nopeUsers = nopePeopleTV.users, !nopeUsers.isEmpty {
    scrollView.addSubview(nopePeopleLabel)
    scrollView.addSubview(nopePeopleTV)
    let nopeTVHeight: CGFloat = CGFloat(nopeUsers.count) * 60
    nopePeopleLabel.anchor(top: maybePeopleLabel.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 20, paddingLeft: padding, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: padding, width: 0, height: 0)
    nopePeopleTV.anchor(top: nopePeopleLabel.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: scrollView.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 5, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: nopeTVHeight)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var lowestObjAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor = descLabel.bottomAnchor
```

Override this property everytime the lowest anchor changes and you'll be fine. In code this would look like this:

```
if let sureUsers = surePeopleTV.users, !sureUsers.isEmpty {
    scrollView.addSubview(surePeopleLabel)
    scrollView.addSubview(surePeopleTV)
    let sureTVHeight: CGFloat = CGFloat(sureUsers.count) * 60
    surePeopleLabel.anchor(top: lowestObjAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 20, paddingLeft: padding, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: padding, width: 0, height: 0)
    surePeopleTV.anchor(top: surePeopleLabel.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 5, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: sureTVHeight)

    lowestObjAnchor = surePeopleTV.bottomAnchor
}
```

Comment: Please add more details with the code, to better understand the solution, and mark your answer to correct, whenever you can be able to do.

Comment: @BhavinKansagara you need to wait 2 days to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You’re overthinking this.

Don’t remove any objects (labels or table views). Instead, just change their heights (and the intervening spacing constraints) to zero. This is actually easiest if each label-table pair is inside a superview that can then be adjusted as needed.

Alternatively, use a stack view. It automatically deals with views as you hide and show them, adjusting the constraints for you.